# Clone or Remove specific Variables, Components and Task across all packages in an SSIS Solution

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I am not very good with C# but was wondering if anyone has ever created a script that duplicates/clones or removes specific Variables, Components and Task across all packages in an SSIS Solution.

Comment: You mean to say a script that would remove certain variables within the static packages?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider a package template (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345191.aspx) or BIML (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/)

Comment: Yes on a static package

Comment: Removing Variables across packages via script is fairly simple. Tasks ups the challenge as you might need to deal with re-routing precedence constraints. Components are the hardest as there you have to the metadata satisfied as well as balance the routing between the parent component(s) and destination component(s).

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz (welcome to the tag, please keep contributing) is spot on about Biml. Reverse engineer/decompose your packages into Biml and then it's just a matter of applying sufficient transformers to conform your packages into their new shape.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any "silver bullet" here - SSIS is notoriously fussy and fragile.

The BIDS Helper Add-In does have some useful functionality WRT copying, moving and identifying the use of Variables:

http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Variables%20Window%20Extensions&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Found an interest blog from a fellow called Garrette Mondson. I give this a try

http://garrettedmondson.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/dynamically-generate-ssis-packages/